# How to communicate over SSL from a client in Java

Tags: java, rest, ssl, encryption, https

I'm trying to log in to a web server over SSL from a client application.

I don't want the username and password to be sent over plaintext, so I would like to encrypt my traffic and subsequent REST calls using the SSL certificate provided by the web server.

So far, my code retrieves the certificate from the server, and from that I can retrieve the public key.

```
        public void testConnectionTo(String aURL) throws Exception {
        URL destinationURL = new URL(aURL);
        HttpsURLConnection conn = (HttpsURLConnection) destinationURL
                .openConnection();
        conn.connect();
        Certificate[] certs = conn.getServerCertificates();
        for (Certificate cert : certs) {
           System.out.println(cert.getPublicKey());

        }
```

This returns 3 different RSA public Keys. 
Which one do I use, and how (in pseudo code/code) do I use this public key to encrypt my outbound traffic?

Comment: If you are using HTTPS, as in accessing a URL with a `https://` protocol, your traffic is automatically and transparently encrypted. What exactly are you trying to achieve? Getting sever certificates is mostly to check if you accept them.

Comment: So using HTTPS, as I am now, I won't be vulnerable to man in the middle attacks?

Comment: Yes, as long as you are really trusting the certificates that the server gives you, and do not accept outdated ciphers. Here are [ciphers recommendations by Mozilla from 2016](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Server_Side_TLS) if you want the gory details. JVM has its own repository of trusted root certificates, and would normally consult your OS's trusted CA list, too. You can check the connection's certificate additionally if you want to be extra paranoid, and close the connection if you think the certificate may be compromised, or know it is revoked.

Comment: Great. So I would just verify the SSL certificate once at the start of the connection using 
     Certificate.verify()?

Comment: @9000 is incorrect and MITM attacks are a real danger when conecting via an unknown WiFi HotSpot.

Comment: which certificate should I verify, I seem to be getting 3 back.

Comment: You should verify all certificates, and in many aspect (order, name, issuer, expire date, revocation, etc)  RFC https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5280 describes how to do it.

Comment: @zaph: I stated that the traffic is transparently encrypted, without any additional handling. I never stated that this guarantees the absence of MITM, and given a few pointers on topics relevant to certificate and cipher suite checking.

Comment: @zaph: 9000 is correct. Certificates are checked and must be anchored by a trusted root, hostnames are checked to see if they match according to RFC 2818. Pinning increases security by reducing the number of trusted anchors, but it can't always be done unless you know the websites policies *or* you can push out a new version of the app quickly in the event of CA change. Otherwise, you risk committing something called "pinning suicide".

Comment: @zaph: Not exactly sure what your saying but the default checks done by Java HttpsURLConnection are complete. They verify that the certificate is trusted and that it corresponds to the hostname that was requested, per RFC 2818. Pinning is an additional check that is needed because there are too many trusted CA's, many of whom really aren't so trustworthy.

Comment: @JamesKPolk & 9000 I was wrong and learned more about SSL pinning. I have deleted my incorrect comments.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using an `https://` as the URL protocol, the underlying the connection will automatically be encrypted, you don't need to do anything with the connection's server certs.

You shouldn't need to take any additional action to encrypt/decrypt the traffic.

The value for inspecting the certifications would be to see things like who the issuing agency is, and if you needed to do additional validation against the certificate .. for instance, if you were to validate that the cert was issued to the site that you are connecting to, to attempt to detect if somebody is launching a man-in-middle with an unmatched cert.

But in terms of straight wire encryption (preventing eavesdroppers) .. that is done automatically.

Comment: Thanks, where does verifying the SSL certificate come in to play?

Comment: For Instance, if the cert is an instanceof X509Certificate you could then check to see what the signing algorithm was, or who the issuing authority was.  Then, if the cert didn't meet your standards, you could refuse to accept the connection.

Comment: Any advice on how I would specify my certificate standards/check the certificate matches my standards?

Comment: Wire encryption is that you can't just look at the packet stream and see what is in the packets (the way you can with http)  b/c the data is encrypted automatically with the certs public key .. whether or not you trust that cert is a different issue.

Comment: My statement about the encryption is valid because per the original question the concern was that the username/password be encrypted to the endpoint ... which is will be regardless of the certificate, but the side discussion of MITM attacks is valid and should be kept in mind. However, the original request was just to ensure that encryption was taking place at all.

Comment: @zaph I am not disagreeing with you, that is what I am saying, you have to decide if you are going to trust the cert .. i.e. verify that the cert came from who you think it came from.

Comment: @zaph: I'm not familiar with Charles, but proxies like that work because you *explicitly* add the proxy CA cert to your list of trusted certs on the device you  want to MITM. Otherwise it will detect the MiTM.

Comment: How often do you need to verify? Is once sufficient?

Comment: @mrseamus: You don't need to verify anything,  it's all done for you.

Comment: If I don't verify, then I'm open to MITM attacks.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I was wrong and learned more about SSL pinning. Essentially it protects against a user being able to add a certificate to the trusted list and thus protects against a user seeing the unencrypted traffic. his can also extend to organizations that add certificates to user's computers. In general SSL pinning is not needed to protect against MiTM attacks.  I have deleted my incorrect comments.